# why is my index undefined

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable”  and “Notice: Undefined index”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

im trying to create a simple `login and register page` and i am getting these errors on my `index .php` page,why is my index undefined these are the errors i am getting

```
Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\forum part two\index.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\forum part two\index.php on line 8
```

the codes on line 7 and 8 these respectively

```
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$password = $_SESSION['password'];
```

this is my index page

```
<?php
//This will start a session
session_start();

$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$password = $_SESSION['password'];

//Check do we have username and password
if(!$username && !$password){
echo "Welcome Guest! <br> <a href=login.php>Login</a> | <a href=register.php>Register</a>";
}else{
echo "Welcome ".$username." (<a href=logout.php>Logout</a>)";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting those errors because your session has not been declared earlier,So you need to check if your session is declared earlier. you can use php [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) or [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function

```
<?php
//This will start a session
session_start();
$username ='';$password ='';
if(!empty($_SESSION['username']))//check if it is defined
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];

if(!empty($_SESSION['password']))//check if it is defined
    $password = $_SESSION['password'];

//Check do we have username and password
if($username=='' && $password==''){
   echo "Welcome Guest! <br> <a href=login.php>Login</a> | <a href=register.php>Register</a>";
}else{
echo "Welcome ".$username." (<a href=logout.php>Logout</a>)";
}
?>
```

Comment: This will just give a "Notice: Undefined variable" instead if the session's index is not set, because `$username` and `$password` never get set if they don't exist in the session.

Comment: now this will throw an undefined variable errors on username and pasword on the if condition when they are not set. Declare them to be false first.

Comment: @Sibu i tried the errors are going but its not registering

Comment: @theuserkaps where are you declaring your session variable, if it is declared it will show username, otherwise guest details will be shown

Comment: i figured it out i think i have another problem with the register page

Answer (score 2):

Check to see if the `$_SESSION's` store any values..

I'll give you an example:

```
  <?php
 //This will start a session
 session_start();

 if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
 {
     $username = $_SESSION['username'];
}else{
  $username = null;
}
var_dump($username);

// Would return NULL. SESSION IS NOT SET.
// if I add $_SESSION['username'] = "Phorce" session set, will return phorce.
?>
```

Or: `var_dump($_SESSION['username']);`

Hope this helps :) It could be that `$_SESSION['username']` isn't registering.

Comment: This will just give a "Notice: Undefined variable" instead if the session's index is not set, because `$username` and `$password` never get set if they don't exist in the session.

Answer (score 1):

Please check that there is value assigned to session variable before using it.

```
<?php
//This will start a session
session_start();

$username ="";
$password ="";
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
$username = $_SESSION['username'];

if(isset($_SESSION['password ']))
$password = $_SESSION['password'];

//Check do we have username and password
if(!$username && !$password){
echo "Welcome Guest! <br> <a href=login.php>Login</a> | <a href=register.php>Register</a>";
}else{
echo "Welcome ".$username." (<a href=logout.php>Logout</a>)";
}
?>
```